# Calculating Total, Grand Total and Percentage in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Hi all and Thanks in Advance for all your support.
I have a data where i need to show Total, Grand Total and percentage of a Team trained, Tested and Certified.

Sharing the datafile below. I need to plot a pie chart which says that this much are trained, tested and certified and same for if not done it.

```
Name    Team    JavaTrained     JavaTested      JavaCertified
A1      EPC     Yes             Yes             Yes
A2      SSDP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A3      SYMP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A4      Target  Yes             Yes             Yes
A5      MI      Yes             Yes             Yes
A6      MR      Yes             Yes             Yes
A7      EPC     Yes             Yes             Yes
A8      SSDP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A9      SYMP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A10     Target  Yes             Yes             Yes
A11     MI      Yes             Yes             Yes
A12     MR      Yes             Yes             Yes
A13     EPC     Yes             Yes             Yes
A14     SSDP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A15     SYMP    Yes             Yes             No
A16     Target  Yes             Yes             No
A17     MI      Yes             Yes             Yes
A18     MR      Yes             Yes             Yes
A19     EPC     Yes             Yes             Yes
A20     SSDP    NA              NA              NA
A21     SYMP    NA              NA              NA
A22     Target  NA              NA              NA
A23     MI      Yes             Yes             Yes
A24     MR      Yes             Yes             Yes
A25     EPC     Yes             Yes             Yes
A26     SSDP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A27     SYMP    Yes             Yes             No
A28     Target  Yes             Yes             Yes
A29     MI      Yes             Yes             No
A30     MR      Yes             Yes             Yes
A31     EPC     Yes             Yes             Yes
A32     SSDP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A33     SYMP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A34     Target  Yes             Yes             Yes
A35     MI      Yes             Yes             No
A36     MR      Yes             Yes             Yes
A37     EPC     Yes             Yes             No
A38     SSDP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A39     SYMP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A40     Target  Yes             Yes             No
A41     MI      Yes             Yes             No
A42     MR      Yes             Yes             Yes
A43     EPC     Yes             Yes             Yes
A44     SSDP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A45     SYMP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A46     Target  Yes             Yes             Yes
A47     MI      Yes             Yes             Yes
A48     MR      Yes             Yes             No
A49     EPC     NA              NA              NA
A50     SSDP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A51     SYMP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A52     Target  Yes             Yes             No
A53     MI      Yes             Yes             Yes
A54     MR      Yes             Yes             Yes
A55     EPC     Yes             Yes             Yes
A56     SSDP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A57     SYMP    Yes             Yes             No
A58     Target  NA              NA              NA
A59     MI      Yes             Yes             Yes
A60     MR      Yes             Yes             Yes
A61     EPC     Yes             Yes             Yes
A62     SSDP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A63     SYMP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A64     Target  Yes             Yes             Yes
A65     MI      Yes             Yes             Yes
A66     MR      Yes             Yes             No
A67     EPC     Yes             Yes             No
A68     SSDP    NA              NA              NA
A69     SYMP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A70     Target  Yes             Yes             Yes
A71     MI      Yes             Yes             Yes
A72     MR      Yes             Yes             Yes
A73     EPC     Yes             Yes             Yes
A74     SSDP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A75     SYMP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A76     Target  Yes             Yes             Yes
A77     MI      Yes             Yes             Yes
A78     MR      Yes             Yes             Yes
A79     EPC     Yes             Yes             Yes
A80     SSDP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A81     SYMP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A82     Target  Yes             Yes             Yes
A83     EPC                 
A84     SSDP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A85     SYMP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A86     Target  Yes             Yes             Yes
A87     MI      Yes             Yes             Yes
A88     MR      Yes             Yes             Yes
A89     EPC     Yes             Yes             Yes
A90     SSDP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A91     SYMP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A92     Target  No              No              No
A93     MI      Yes             Yes             Yes
A94     MR      Yes             Yes             Yes
A95     EPC     Yes             Yes             Yes
A96     SSDP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A97     SYMP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A98     Target  Yes             Yes             Yes
A99     MI      Yes             Yes             Yes
A100    MR      Yes             Yes             Yes
A101    EPC     Yes             Yes             Yes
A102    SSDP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A103    SYMP    Yes             Yes             Yes
A104    Target  Yes             Yes             Yes
A105    MI      Yes             Yes             Yes
A106    MR      Yes             Yes             Yes
A107    EPC     Yes             Yes             No
```

I want to calculate something like this:-

```
Column Labels                   
                           NA   No  Yes (blank)  Grand Total    Certified %
    Count of Java Trained   6   1   99           106            93%
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add these simple measures to your table and place them in the **Values** field in the pie charts:

[image: Trained]
[image: Tested]
[image: Certified]

There are a few ways to get the percentages below but the easiest is to just add in a matrix where the **Total Certified** measure is added to the Values field twice (one being the actual values, and the other showing as a percentage of the grand total.

[image: Percentage]

The matrix should then show the following:

[image: Matrix]

Let me know if this helps or if you would like to explore a different DAX solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can Unpivot the data in the **Query Editor** then you can create a matrix to show your data:

[image]